# Need example for web api post with multiple parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In c#, Need example for web api post with multiple parameter ,Below i have attached my sample code.Please look into the InsertLeave method.In my code without CompanyId parameters working fine. When i add the companyid not able to invoke.

```
 namespace AeS.SaaSAPI_2116
{
   [RoutePrefix("{CompanyId}/{SecurityKey}")]
   public class LeaveController : ApiController
   {


     [HttpPost]
    [Route("{APIName}/x")]
    public string InsertLeave(List<LeaveRequest> objList, string CompanyId)
    {
        foreach (LeaveRequest LR in objList)
        {

        }
        return "Sucess ";
    }


    }
}

public class LeaveRequest
{
    [Required]
    public string EMP_STAFFID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LEAVE_TYPE { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: You'll have to create a single class wrapping all your parameters.

Comment: Is the company id passed along to the server in the POST body or as a parameter in the URI?

Comment: parameter in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use send your parameter to the server by request body, You will have to create a single class that wrapping your all parameters.You can use model binding to resolve this kind of issue